# How to query from one to many tables in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

Hello kind people of this group, I am quite new with MySql, and am learning the basics...
I am training on the following structure:

Store (id,name)

VideoCase(id, storeID, genre)

Video (id, videoCaseID, title)

Actor(id,videoID,name)

Now, I would like to get in my MySql query, the ID and name of a specific store, together with the id and name of every single actor from the videos avaliable in the store.

so my query is:

```
SELECT     store.id as 'Store Id' ,
       store.name as 'Name', actor.id AS 'actor ID', actor.name as 'Actors Name'
       FROM store 
       INNER JOIN videoCase ON store.id = videoCase.storeID
       INNER JOIN video ON videoCase.id = video.videoCaseID
       INNER JOIN actor ON video.id = actor.videoID
       WHERE store.id = 30
```

This query gives me the correct result, but I am not sure if this is the correct way or if this can be optimized, all these JOIN may be avoided to go straight bewtween Store and Actor, or am I doing things correctly?
Thanks

Comment: There is no relationship between store and actor so you have to do what you have done.

Comment: What do you do about 2 copies of a video?  And might those copies be in different "cases"?